# Use average value theorem to find c for indefinite integral (piecewise)

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Given a piecewise function

$$   f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      x & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
      3-x & 1 < x \leq 3\\
\end{array} 
\right. $$

and it is integrable in $[0,3]$. Then Can I apply the average value theorem ($\frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$)? I think so because it is integrable, so it is continuous and thus I can use it. But the next question is: is there multiple $c$, for which $f(c)= \frac{1}{3-0} \int_{3}^{0}f(x)dx$? Notice that $a=0$ and $b = 3$ since this is the interval I said is integrable. For this question I think I should divide the integral into 2 parts, $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$ and $\int_{1}^{3}f(x)dx$ because of the piecewise function. I did that and still can't see if there is more than one $c$ value.

Comment: A function being integrable does not mean it is continuous. If it were continuous, there is guaranteed to be such a $c$, but you have to actually do the calculation to see if there is more than one. What did you get for $\int_0^3f(x)dx$? Since each component of the piecewise function is linear, it should be straightforward to see if a solution exists, and if there are multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a function is continuous at some point if

$\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x) = f(a)$

You can see that it is not continuous if you apply the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition for example.

And then by definition of the Mean value theorem $f$ should be continuous, but it is not, therefore you need to partition the integral into two parts.

Comment: Yep, that was a mistake on my part . Now can we still find an average value if it's not continuous? Is there a c such that $f(c)= \frac{1}{3-0} \int_{3}^{0}f(x)dx$?